Vanishing of Cech cohomology of a flabby sheaf
Can someone provide an explicit proof for this fact? Fix a covering, take a cocycle then construct a cochain whose coboundary is the cocycle. Presumably this could be down by extending the components of this cocyle using subjectivity from flabbiness.

I wonder if more generally, a "flabby" simplicial set (or would it need to be a simplicial coset?) has zero cohomology.  If so, then that would give the original question as a corollary, and it might simplify the notation a bit to abstract out the $\Gamma(U_{ijk}, \mathscr{F})$ etc. that are involved.

Any idea what a proof might look like?

Not sure, maybe something where you start by e.g. extending a section of $\Gamma(U_1 \cap U_2 \cap U_3, \mathscr{F})$ to a section of $\Gamma(U_1 \cap U_2, \mathscr{F})$ and then you keep adding in needed corrections (and possibly there will be some gluing needed too using the cocycle condition) until eventually you get something whose coboundary is what you wanted?  And perhaps it's possible to construct solutions in some roughly "triangular" form where certain entries are 0, analogous to a certain proof of the Poincare lemma?  Not at all sure, but seems possible...

Maybe to try to figure it out, you could observe that if $n=3$ then an element of $\Gamma(U_1\cap U_2\cap U_3, \mathscr{F})$ is automatically a cocycle, and you can take an extension to $\Gamma(U_1\cap U_2, \mathscr{F})$ and 0 in $\Gamma(U_1\cap U_3, \mathscr{F})$ and $\Gamma(U_2\cap U_3, \mathscr{F})$ to get something with the desired coboundary.  Now, maybe try the case $n=4$ and see how to add corrections over $U_i \cap U_4$ to the previous solution to get what you need in that case?  If you could solve that, hopefully it could give some ideas for the general inductive step.

I strongly suspect no explicit proof exists. It is equivalent to argue flabby sheaves have vanishing ordinary sheaf cohomology, and this is easy … with an argument involving Zorn’s lemma; involving it in an essential way. Even then, the only proof I know involves the fact Cech cohomology wrt a cover is a derived functor via the universal delta functor theorem, and injective resolutions, though they can be made explicit, really don’t want to be made explicit
